# Are 3 identical parameters possible with .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

**@anubhava** and **@RavinderSingh13** have helped me tremendously so far in understanding more about .htaccess and rewrite rules. However, even though both the first rule (with one parameter: **$id**) and the second rule (with two parameters: **$id** and **$name**) works for rewriting the url, my third rule I attempted with also two parameters (**$id** and **$class**) fails, and does not rewrite the final url. Below is my entire file so far. I would like to add that the **$class** parameter is in the format of **a-class**, **b-class**, etc., so maybe that could be a contributor to the the rewrite not working? Thank you for helping me continue to learn thus far!

```
RewriteEngine on
--1st rule with one parameter: $id--
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^file\.php$ /directory/%1? [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^directory/(\d+)/?$ /directory/file.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

--2nd rule with two parameters: $id and $name--
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/file\.php\?id=(\d+)&name=(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /directory/%1/%2? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^directory/(\d+)/(.*)/?$ /directory/file.php?id=$1&name=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

--My attempt at the third rule following the example from the second, but this rule fails. Parameters are $id and $class--
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/file\.php\?id=(\d+)&class=(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /directory/%1/%2? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^directory/(\d+)/(.*)/?$ /directory/file.php?id=$1&class=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts in your question(keep it up), what's happening when you hit your class url now?

Comment: You have two rules with identical patterns . The engine will only serve the first one.

Comment: I'm just returned a bunch of undefined variables on my page. However, it's not an issue with the variables themselves since the page with the class and id parameters works correctly when I access it without the url rewrite. I'll also add that I'm attempting to get the url rewrite in this format, similar to the other urls: **http://ipaddress/directory/47/s-class** In this case, **47** is the **id** parameter and **s-class** is the **class** parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples and considering class word will be there always in your 3rd url try following rules. Also you need not to write RewriteEngine ON many times, only 1 time starting of file is enough.

```
RewriteEngine on
##1st rule with one parameter: $id--
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^file\.php$ /directory/%1? [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^directory/(\d+)/?$ /directory/file.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

##Parameters are $id and $class
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/file\.php\?id=(\d+)&class=(\w+-class)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /directory/%1/%2? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^directory/(\d+)/(\w+-class)/?$ /directory/file.php?id=$1&class=$2 [NC,L,QSA]


##Rule with two parameters: $id and $name--
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/file\.php\?id=(\d+)&name=(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /directory/%1/%2? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^directory/(\d+)/(.*)/?$ /directory/file.php?id=$1&name=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: I appreciate your solution since now the url successfully redirects without undefined variables. However, now the **$class** filter will not work correctly. Instead, it will just display all data normally without the **$class** filter being applied.
For instance, normally, this url will filter that data: **IPAddress/directory/file.php?id=47&class=s**. Which indicates that the **$class** filter is now only working with the original url and not the rewrite. Now that I think about it, is the issue that the original url only shows **s** as the **$class** instead of **s-class**?

Comment: @ccc, could you please do let me know if you have run exact rules posted by me(I edited them after 1 min of my post, by changing order of them), kindly confirm once.

Comment: Yes, as I was working on your original answer, I saw that you swapped the order of the second and third rules, so I also swapped them around on my end.

Comment: @ccc, ok I have changed Rules now, now I am trying to catch `class=a-class` etc string in class variable passed to index.php file, let me know how it goes.

Comment: Same issue as before except now, I notice an error message: **Notice: Undefined index: s-class in /directory/file.php**

Comment: @ccc, you are passing class parameter to file.php is your code knowing what is class parameter doing? I mean you have coded for that parameter, looks like its not coded inside it.

Comment: Ah yes! This works now! Just had to fix an issue on my end by making the **$class** variable **s-class** in the array instead of **s**. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @ccc, Your welcome cheers and happy learning, keep sharing Good Q & A on this great forums, cheers.